# Which Oracle version is best for Windows 10 and how to check Database connection in Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: oracle, codeigniter, oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried to install Oracle 19c and 18c in window 10. After installing the oracle 19c i can't able to create database connection throught oracle sql developer tool. Please check this image
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHnOD.png)

Comment: don't install any oracle db on your win10 machine - use a docker image or a virtual machine - we make a vbox appliance for you even. This has 19c on it https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/databaseappdev-vm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

19c doesn't have express edition, so - if you really installed 19c, its SID most probably isn't XE.

If you installed 18cXE, then try to put "XE" into **Service Name** (instead of into the "SID" field on SQL Developer's login screen).